# Hadoop Installation Issue on Windows

Tags: windows, hadoop, namenode

I have been trying to install `Hadoop` on Windows 7 for quite sometime now. I am following this [blog](http://toodey.com/2015/08/10/hadoop-installation-on-windows-without-cygwin-in-10-mints/) for instructions. But unfortunately I have not been be able to run the `Namenode`. 
There seems to be issue with `hdfs-site.xml` file but I dont see anything wrong in it. Please have a look at it

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>1</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
       <value>F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
     <value>F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\datanode</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

and the error log that I am getting on running `hdfs namenode -format` command in command prompt:

```
C:\Users\ABC>hdfs namenode -format
Hadoop common not found.
16/08/05 12:44:53 INFO namenode.NameNode: STARTUP_MSG:
/************************************************************
STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode
STARTUP_MSG:   host = ABC-PC/172.20.0.51
STARTUP_MSG:   args = [-format]
STARTUP_MSG:   version = 2.7.2
STARTUP_MSG:   classpath = F:\hadoop-2.7.2\etc\hadoop;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hado
op\common\lib\commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib
\jersey-server-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jets3t-0.9.0.jar;
F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\shar
e\hadoop\common\lib\hadoop-auth-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\li
b\commons-digester-1.8.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\log4j-1.2.17.
jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\java-xmlbuilder-0.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.
7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\curator-client-2.7.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoo
p\common\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\xmlen
c-0.52.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\activation-1.1.jar;F:\hadoop-
2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\
hadoop\common\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\
curator-framework-2.7.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-ker
beros-codec-2.0.0-M15.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\netty-3.6.2.Fi
nal.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;F:
\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar;F:\hadoop
-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\apacheds-i18n-2.0.0-M15.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share
\hadoop\common\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\comm
ons-configuration-1.6.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\asm-3.2.jar;F:
\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\h
adoop\common\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\j
ackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\curator-rec
ipes-2.7.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\mockito-all-1.8.5.jar;F:\
hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-math3-3.1.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\sha
re\hadoop\common\lib\commons-net-3.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib
\snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsch-0.1.42.jar
;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\shar
e\hadoop\common\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common
\lib\api-util-1.0.0-M20.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsp-api-2.1.
jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\httpclient-4.2.5.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2
\share\hadoop\common\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\li
b\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-lang-2.6.j
ar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\xz-1.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hado
op\common\lib\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\hado
op-annotations-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jaxb-api-2.2.2.
jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jersey-json-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\
share\hadoop\common\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\com
mon\lib\httpcore-4.2.5.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\avro-1.7.4.ja
r;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;F:\ha
doop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\had
oop\common\lib\api-asn1-api-1.0.0-M20.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\li
b\gson-2.2.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;F:\
hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\junit-4.11.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop
\common\lib\jettison-1.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\jsr305-3.0.
0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;F:\hadoo
p-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\h
adoop\common\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\s
lf4j-api-1.7.10.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-httpclient-3
.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;F:\ha
doop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\lib\paranamer-2.3.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoo
p\common\hadoop-nfs-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-
2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\common\hadoop-common-2.7.2-tests.jar;F:\h
adoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jersey-serve
r-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;F:\hadoop
-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hd
fs\lib\netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\log4j-1.
2.17.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2
.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\xmlenc-0.52.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib
\xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9
.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-daemon-1.0.13.jar;F:\hadoo
p-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop
\hdfs\lib\htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib
\jetty-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\asm-3.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.
7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\l
ib\xml-apis-1.3.04.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-codec-1.4.j
ar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop
-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\
lib\commons-lang-2.6.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\protobuf-java-2.5
.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2
\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-cli-1.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib
\jsr305-3.0.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\commons-logging-1.1.3.ja
r;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2-tests.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\
share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop-hdfs-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\hdfs\hadoop
-hdfs-nfs-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-compress-1.4.1
.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2
\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\
lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;F
:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-client-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share
\hadoop\yarn\lib\jetty-util-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\act
ivation-1.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.ja
r;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jaxb-impl-2.2.3-1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\sh
are\hadoop\yarn\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\
commons-collections-3.2.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\aopalliance-
1.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jetty-6.1.26.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\s
hare\hadoop\yarn\lib\asm-3.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-i
o-2.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-codec-1.4.jar;F:\hadoop-
2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-guice-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\ya
rn\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\zooke
eper-3.4.6-tests.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;F:
\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\stax-api-1.0-2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\had
oop\yarn\lib\jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\guic
e-3.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\guava-11.0.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2
\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib
\commons-lang-2.6.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\xz-1.0.jar;F:\hadoop
-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jackson-xc-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\
yarn\lib\jaxb-api-2.2.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jersey-json-1.
9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.
7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\
lib\guice-servlet-3.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-cli-1.2.
jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\jettison-1.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share
\hadoop\yarn\lib\jsr305-3.0.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\commons-
logging-1.1.3.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-api-2.7.2.jar;F:
\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-2.7
.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-2.7.2.jar;
F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-2.7.2.jar;F
:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-server-sharedcachemanager-2.7.2.jar
;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-applications-distributedshell-2.7
.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-applications-unmanaged-am-l
auncher-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-registry-2.7.2.j
ar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-client-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.
2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-common-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\ya
rn\hadoop-yarn-server-common-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-
yarn-server-nodemanager-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\yarn\hadoop-yarn-
server-tests-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\commons-compre
ss-1.4.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-server-1.9.jar;F:
\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\leveldbjni-all-1.8.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\
share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-core-1.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapr
educe\lib\log4j-1.2.17.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jackson-co
re-asl-1.9.13.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\netty-3.6.2.Final.j
ar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\aopalliance-1.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.
2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\asm-3.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\
lib\commons-io-2.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jersey-guice-1
.9.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar;
F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\javax.inject-1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\sh
are\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\ma
preduce\lib\guice-3.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\xz-1.0.jar;
F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\hadoop-annotations-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoo
p-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share
\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\avro-1.7.4.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\
guice-servlet-3.0.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\junit-4.11.jar;
F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2
\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\paranamer-2.3.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapre
duce\hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapreduce\
hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapred
uce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-common-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\mapred
uce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.2-tests.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hado
op\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\m
apreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-shuffle-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\
mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop\ma
preduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.7.2.jar;F:\hadoop-2.7.2\share\hadoop
\mapreduce\hadoop-mapreduce-client-app-2.7.2.jar
STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop.git -r b16
5c4fe8a74265c792ce23f546c64604acf0e41; compiled by 'jenkins' on 2016-01-26T00:08
Z
STARTUP_MSG:   java = 1.7.0_79
************************************************************/
16/08/05 12:44:53 INFO namenode.NameNode: createNameNode [-format]
16/08/05 12:44:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop libra
ry for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/08/05 12:44:54 ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\na
menode. Please check hdfs configuration.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: F:\had
oop-2.7.2\data\namenode
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3039)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringAsURI(Util.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringCollectionAsURIs(Util
.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getStorageDirs(FS
Namesystem.java:1400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceDirs(
FSNamesystem.java:1355)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:
966)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNo
de.java:1429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:15
54)
16/08/05 12:44:54 WARN common.Util: Path F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode should be
 specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
16/08/05 12:44:54 ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\na
menode. Please check hdfs configuration.
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in opaque part at index 2: F:\had
oop-2.7.2\data\namenode
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2829)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3002)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3039)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:595)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringAsURI(Util.java:48)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Util.stringCollectionAsURIs(Util
.java:98)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getStorageDirs(FS
Namesystem.java:1400)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceEdits
Dirs(FSNamesystem.java:1445)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNamespaceEdits
Dirs(FSNamesystem.java:1414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:
971)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNo
de.java:1429)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:15
54)
16/08/05 12:44:54 WARN common.Util: Path F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode should be
 specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
Formatting using clusterid: CID-e302dfa9-9520-4074-9247-d9f09cd0f882
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: No KeyProvider found.
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsLock is fair:true
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.lim
it=1000
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.namenode.datanode.re
gistration.ip-hostname-check=true
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.namenode.startup.delay.
block.deletion.sec is set to 000:00:00:00.000
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: The block deletion will sta
rt around 2016 Aug 05 12:44:54
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 19.3 MB
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enab
le=false
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication
= 1
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication
= 512
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication
= 1
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams
= 2
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval
= 3000
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer
= false
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxNumBlocksToLog
= 1000
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = ABC (auth:S
IMPLE)
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory 966.7 MB = 9.7 MB
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: ACLs enabled? false
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: XAttrs enabled? true
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSDirectory: Maximum size of an xattr: 16384
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than
10 times
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map cachedBlocks
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: 0.25% max memory 966.7 MB = 2.4 MB
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^19 = 524288 entries
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pc
t = 0.9990000128746033
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanode
s = 0
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension
  = 30000
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.window.n
um.buckets = 10
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.num.user
s = 10
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO metrics.TopMetrics: NNTop conf: dfs.namenode.top.windows.
minutes = 1,5,25
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled

16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total
 heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map NameNodeRetryCache
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 966.7 MB = 29
7.0 KB
16/08/05 12:44:54 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^16 = 65536 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode ? (Y or
N) y
16/08/05 12:55:16 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-124614392
5-172.20.0.51-1470383716578
16/08/05 12:55:16 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\na
menode has been successfully formatted.
16/08/05 12:55:16 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 ima
ges with txid >= 0
16/08/05 12:55:16 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
16/08/05 12:55:16 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at ABC-PC/192.168.0.51
************************************************************/
```

and can anybody please guide what I am doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to @Binary Nerd for setting things correctly. But now I am facing another problem, even though the System Architecture is 32-bits the `NameNode` is not started and following error appears (excerpt):

```
CreateProcess error=216, This version of %1 is not compatible with the version of
Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether
you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact
 the software publisher
```

Comment: You should really ask another question if you have a new problem, which this is. People will have already looked at this question and decided if they can provide an answer or not. This issue will be most likely be a mismatch between your systems architecture (32-bits) and the one hadoop is built for.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Looks like this is the main error you're getting is:

`ERROR common.Util: Syntax error in URI F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode.`

You've specified it as:

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode</value>
</property>
```

Perhaps the first thing to try is using the same format as the blog (forward slashes):

`F:/hadoop-2.7.2/data/namenode`

If that doesnt help you can try making it a valid [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Windows_2):

`file:///f:/hadoop-2.7.2/data/namenode`

Comment: good catch :) file:///f:/hadoop-2.7.2/data/namenode is working fine

Comment: Thanks, that helped.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: `file:///f:/hadoop-2.7.2/data/namenode` worked for me using version 3.1.2

Answer (score 2):

Kinda late, but for future reference.

My problem was that I copy pasted the hdfs-site.xml from the tutorial and a special character,probably newline, was added in this line

```
<property><name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name><value>/hadoop-
2.6.0/data/name</value><final>true</final></property>
```

so just go and delete it

```
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name><value>/hadoop-2.6.0/data/name</value><final>true</final>
</property>
```

this sort of installation problems are the worst...they just discourage you so much

Answer (score 0):

In hdfs-site.xml file, change the `F:\hadoop-2.7.2\data\namenode` to the `file:/F:/hadoop-2.7.2/data/namenode`

After this error will be resolved